# change site if the browser internet explorer 5 - 6 - 7

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, internet-explorer-6

PLEASE I NEED A HTACCESS SCRIPT
if the user..have  mie6-7 ... SERVER redirect HIM  to another page

using htaccess please

i am using joomla.... i want it to change template ONLY

Comment: can u please make it redirect to  index.php?$1&tp=1&template=beez
$1 is the site url
so index.php?option=com_content to index.php?option=com_content?tp=1&template=beez

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} MSIE\ ([67])\
RewriteRule ^.*$ newpage.html [L]
```

Comment: can u please make it redirect to  index.php?$1&tp=1&template=beez
$1 is the site url
so index.php?option=com_content to index.php?option=com_content?tp=1&template=beez